# IIS 7.5 302 Redirect Due to Invalid Header

Tags: .net, wcf, http, iis

I am working on deploying some legacy software to a new web server that has been working flawlessly for years but am getting some odd 302 redirects that we do not receive on our development machines or on our existing production machine.

Here are the details:

1. It is an ASP.Net WCF REST service deployed to IIS 7.5
2. Requests to all functions but 1 at the endpoint work as intended.
3. The request causing the redirect is a POST with a file attached to the packet.
4. The client connecting to the endpoint is putting in a different URL in the header than the URL they are actually posting to.

I have enabled Failed Request Tracing and the reason for the redirect is "HTTP/1.1 302 object Moved".  We do not have any HTTP Redirects defined on the server, so IIS or some other component is causing the redirect without our intention.  Here is an excerpt from the log file for a successful request:

[Successful Request From Development Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeKQU.png)

Notice the "url" in the log file is not the actual DNS entry for the IP address the client software is POSTing the data to.

Here is an example of what is put in the header for the response back to the client, specifically the Location of where to redirect to, which does not exist:

[Redirect to Non-Existant Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDi6Y.png)

It's odd that the redirect is happening, but what is really odd to me is the URL that it is being redirected to.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have verbose WCF tracing/logging enabled?  For both the message and trace?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the tools needed to review the svclog file, and those files are daunting without some sort of viewer.  I can give it a shot, though I believe the redirect is happening before the service method is executed.  Any ideas on what to look for in the svclog file?

Comment: maybe an http to https redirect?